# Display Rows Based From Two Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has 2 foreign keys from the same table

```
UserID     Name
1          Alpha
2          Bravo
3          Charlie
4          Delta
5          Foxtrot

Record     UserID     UserID2
1          1          5
2          3
3          4
```

Is it possible to display them into multiple rows?

```
Record      Name
1           Alpha
1           Foxtrot
2           Charlie
3           Delta
```

I tried using INNER JOIN / JOIN but only works with one foreign key (UserID).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More simple way to do this:

```
Select t2.record AS Record,Name
From t1 inner join t2
on t1.userId = t2.UserID or t1.userId = t2.userid2
```

Comment: I find this solution simple and this is the first time I've seen OR from JOIN statement/s. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use two joins, in this case `left join` to put the values on one row:

```
select t1.record, t2a.name, t2b.name
from t1 left join
     t2 t2a
     on t2a.userid = t1.userid left join
     t2 t2b
     on t2b.userid = t1.userid2;
```

For separate rows, use `union all`:

```
select t1.record, t2.name
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.userid = t1.userid
union all
select t1.record, t2.name
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.userid = t1.userid2
order by record;
```